# Reading the JLD output file of "Julia's OneSampleTTest" in Python

Tags: python, julia, h5py

I have a piece of Julia code, which uses "HypothesisTests" package. It basically runs a series of t-test using OneSampleTTest, and stores them all into one jld file. Through Julia, I can see that the contents for one OneSampleTTest is as follows.

[image]

I would like to write a Python script to read elements from this file, for example, "two-sided p-value".

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File("filename.jld", "r")
test = f["p_value_Never_vs_AtoBat60_FP"][()]
print(test)
```

I am using h5py package, but when I print the element (here, p_value_Never_vs_AtoBat60_FP), I get the following output, which is clearly the pointers not the objects.

```
(100000, <HDF5 object reference>, 99999, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>)
```

How can I retrieve the objects from the pointers in Python?

Thanks and sorry for the long question!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...this is the second question today about accessing HDF5 object references with h5py. An object reference points to another object in the file (typically another dataset, but could also be a group). Accessing data from object references is slightly more complicated than reading a dataset as an array of floats or ints. First you have to de-reference the object reference, then read the data from the referenced object. Not hard, just more involved.  You can get the details here: [h5py documentation on object and region references](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/refs.html#object-and-region-references).

The h5py output you show creates some questions (for me).  Typically HDF5 datasets are homogeneous: -- all array values are the dtype. It looks like your dataset contains both integers and object references, which is very unusual.

Using your file, getting the data from the reference is done something like this (hard to write perfect code without the H5 file for testing):

```
import h5py
with h5py.File("filename.jld", "r") as h5f:
    ds_name = "p_value_Never_vs_AtoBat60_FP"
    # create a h5py dataset object (can be used like a np.array)
    obj_ref_ds = h5f[ds_name]
    print(f"For Dataset name: {ds_name}; shape: {obj_ref_ds.shape}; dtype: {obj_ref_ds.dtype}")
    # the loop below assumes the dataset only contains object references
    # also dimension/shape is assumed to be 1 axis = (n,)
    # this may or MAY NOT be correct
    for n_cnt in range(obj_ref_ds.shape[0]):
        # get dataset object from object reference:
        ref_ds = obj_ref_ds[n_cnt]
        print(f"For object #: {n_cnt}; shape: {ref_ds.shape}; dtype: {ref_ds.dtype}")
```